# Get list of available package versions from Jfrog artifactory to Jenkins deployment job

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-deployment, jfrog-cli

We have an Jenkins deployment project to deploy our API code to Linux servers. The Jenkins project is parameterized with "choice parameter" which gives list of available API's to deploy and next there is "string parameter" where the user need to key in the version of the API which they wish to deploy.

I would like to give the user with list of API package versions which are available in the "JFrog Articatory" when they choose the API name in the "choice parameter"

For example: If the user chooses "Ticket API" from the available list of API's, Jenkins project should go and check in the "JFrog Artifactory" and get the list of available versions of the "Ticket API" and display it to the user to choose the version which he/she wants to deploy.

Is there an way to achieve this, any inputs would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the JFrog Artifactory part, you can use the "[Artifact Version Search](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/artifact-version-search)" API call to get the versions. This will allow you to search for all available artifact versions by GroupId and ArtifactId in local, remote or virtual repositories. Using that API call you can get the versions of a specific artifact in a JSON format:

```
{
"results": [
    {
    "version": "1.2",
    "integration": false
    },{
        "version": "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    "integration": true
    },{
        "version": "1.0",
    "integration": false
    }
]
}
```